# Find conditional probability distribution $P(Y|X=x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{P(x)}$ and create RV $E(Y|X)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A discrete $(X,Y)$ probability distribution is given by the following table:

[image]

The task is:

$a)$ Create Marginal pdf $P(x)$ of $X$ and $P(y)$ of $Y$.

$b)$ Create conditional distribution $P(Y|X=x)$, create rv $E(Y|X)$, and compute $E(E(Y|X)).$

**MY CALCULATION:**

I have done part $a)$ but part $b)$ is confusing me.

By the definition of conditional probability distribution, $P(Y|X=x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{P(x)}$. From here how do I move forward since $f(x,y)$ is in form of table and I cant find a way to perform division here. Last, How I define $E(Y|X)$ as a rv? Any guidance will be appreaciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$P(Y=y|X=x)=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{P(X=x)}=\frac{P(X=x,Y=y)}{\sum_{y'} P(X=x,Y=y')}\\
E[Y|X=x]=\sum_{y} y P(Y=y|X=x)\\
E[E[Y|X]]=\sum_x E[Y|X=x]P(X=x)$$

Hint: A way to verify your answer for b is to use the [law of iterated expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

Comment: I already know what you have shown here Sir. The issue is to solve the last  expression of $P(Y=y|X=x)$ because then for each value of $X=0,1,4$ we have $4$ values of $Y$ which are $0,2,3,5$ Leading to $3*4=12$ values which will be like piece-wise function. Like say for $X=0$ $P(Y=y|X=0)=\frac{P(X=0,Y=y)}{\sum_y P(X=0,Y=y)}$. How do I solve this?

Comment: Correct, for each $X=x$, you have to find four probability masses to specify the conditional distribution of $Y|X=x.$ I modified the notation a bit in my response if that helps.

Comment: You should obtain 12 values in total.